# Python 3.0 replacement for Python 2.0 `.has_key` function

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My program works in Python 2.0 but I need it to work in 3.0 or higher. The problem is that the new Python does not have the `.has_key` function anymore. I need to know how to fix this so it will work in the new version.

```
dictionary = {}

for word in words:
    if dictionary.has_key(word):
        dictionary[word]+=1
    else:
        dictionary[word]=1
bonus = {}
for key in sorted(dictionary.iterkeys()):
    print("%s: %s" % (key,dictionary[key]))
    if len(key)>5: #if word is longer than 5 characters (6 or greater) save to list, where we will get top 10 most common
        bonus[key]=dictionary[key]
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/2to3.html

Answer (score 5):

Use `in` for key testing:

```
if word in dictionary:
```

and replace `.iterkeys()` with `.keys()`; in this case a plain `sorted(dictionary)` would suffice (in either Python 2 *or* 3).

Your code, rewritten a little more compactly with more current techniques, replacing `dictionary` with a [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object:

```
from collections import Counter

dictionary = Counter(words)

bonus = {}
for key in sorted(dictionary):
    print("{}: {}".format(key, dictionary[key]))
    if len(key) > 5:
        bonus[key] = dictionary[key]
```

although you could also use [`Counter.most_common()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) to list keys in order by frequency (high to low) instead.

You may want to read the [Python porting guide](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) if you are porting code from Python 2 to 3.

Comment: Actually, just delete `.iterkeys()` in this case

Comment: Martijn, you should write a tutorial on how to spawn-snipe. +1